# Read char array word by word without string functions

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have char array `words` which contains some words and I have to read all the words from it WITHOUT using string libraries (can't use `strtok`). Here's what I have:

```
int wordsCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; words[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (words[i] == ' ')
        wordsCount++;
}
wordsCount++;

char word[30];
for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    sscanf(words, "%s", word);
}
```

That code reads only first word, I guess I have to add something to `sscanf` but I don't know what or is there ane other method to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you check value of `wordsCount` after 1st `for`?

Comment: What if the word is longer than 30 characters?  Your program has a buffer overrun.  They're teaching how to create insecure and unstable C++ programs?

Comment: What are you supposed to read the words into? Surely not a word? O_o

Comment: @Sniper yes, it works correctly

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie every word is accually shorter than 4 letters so it should fit in this array

Comment: ``char[]`` for string, ``strok``, ... this look more like C than C++.

Comment: @KubaKrzyżyński -- *every word is accually shorter than 4 letters* -- There is no check for this in your program.  Never assume these things, write the code to check that your assumptions are correct that the words are less than 4 characters long.

Comment: You should use `sscanf_s`. Also you are also scanning from the beginning of your `words` array - so you will always find the first word in every iteration.

Comment: Also two or more consecutive spaces (and not even mentioning if the words are separated by tab or some other whitespace character) trips up your loop in a big way.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know all that, to be honest I just need to read names of variables, max 3 charactes for each, no double spaces, maybe I formulated my question bad, sorry about that

Comment: @SimonKraemer unfortunately `std::sscanf_s` does not exist (yet?) in C++. I believe it's coming up in C++17.

Comment: @Quentin My fault... I checked the `C` part of cppreference.com...

Comment: @KubaKrzyżyński -- You don't need a double space -- if your string starts off with a single space, you've been tripped up.  If this is a homework assignment, maybe all of these assumptions you have is supposed to be accounted for in your code?  Teachers do these sorts of things, where they break your code with data you didn't expect.

Comment: @SimonKraemer no worries... I did the same and was greeted by a compiler error :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you wish to keep using the C I/O API, you can make use of the built-in whitespace-skipping functionality of `std::scanf`:

```
int main() {
    char const *str = "She sells seashells by the seashore";
    char word[30];
    unsigned wordLength;

    for(; std::sscanf(str, " %29s%n", word, &wordLength) == 1; str += wordLength)
        std::printf("Read word: \"%s\"\n", word);
}
```

Output:

```
Read word: "She"
Read word: "sells"
Read word: "seashells"
Read word: "by"
Read word: "the"
Read word: "seashore"
```

Of course, you should check for errors better than I didn't ;)

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42678c697e3bc129)

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the pointer after you read:

```
char word[30];
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < wordsCount; i++) {
    sscanf(words, "%s", word);
    offset += strlen(word) + 1;
}
```

<sup>* Above code would not work as expected if you `words` contains consecutive space. You need to think how to fix the offset.</sup>

BTW using `std::string stream` and `std::string` would be easier and safer.

```
std::istringstream iss (words);
std::string word;
while(iss >> word) do_something(word);
```

Comment: after adding `offset` to `words` in sscanf it works, thanks